# Anime where boy fights his way to the top of a dungeon to rescue his kidnapped girlfriend, and kills a Golem by renaming it

Tags: story-identification, anime

It was a long time since I watched the anime so I don't remember very much but it was about a guy chasing after his girlfriend or crush and she had gotten kidnapped and taken to a dungeon and he had to fight his way to the top.

The most specific part I remember is that he fought and killed a Golem or monster called Emet and he killed the Golem/monster by changing its name to Mot (the Hebrew word for die/death)

Comment: Was it "Emeth"
it might be "Monster Masume"

Comment: I believe emeth is Hebrew for "truth".  It is a term closely tied to the history of golems & therefore essentially a trope when talking about them.

Comment: I don't think there's a killing in a light-hearted rom-com anime like *Monster Musume*. Well, apparently this character **doesn't appear in the anime at all**, only on the online social game instead.

Comment: Dungeon animes are pretty common; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_It_Wrong_to_Try_to_Pick_Up_Girls_in_a_Dungeon%3F#Anime

Comment: @LazyReader I have converted your answer to a comment as it was too short to form a full answer, and it seemed to initiate a good discussion. Feel free to post again with a more fully explained and researched answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are thinking of is [*Death March kara Hajimaru Isekai Kyousoukyoku*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/34497/Death_March_kara_Hajimaru_Isekai_Kyousoukyoku)

> Ichirou Suzuki, a programmer nearing his thirties, is drowning in
> work. Worn out, he eventually has a chance to catch up on sleep, only
> to wake up and discover himself in a fantasy RPG world, which is
> mashed together from the games he was debugging in reality. In this
> new place, he realizes that not only has his appearance changed to a
> younger version of himself, but his name has also changed to Satou, a
> nickname he used while running beta tests on games.
>
> However, before Satou can fully grasp his situation, an army of
> lizardmen launch an assault on him. Forced to cast a powerful spell in
> retaliation, Satou wipes them out completely and his level is boosted
> to 310, effectively maximizing his stats. Now, as a high-leveled
> adventurer armed with a plethora of skills and no way to return to
> reality, Satou sets out to explore this magical new world.

[image: A brownish mask with dark grey eye shields and vertical lines on the cheeks, with the text "EMETH" above the brow line]